# ActiveRecord includes doesn't include all parent records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I would like to get all customers and their products that are under category 'Beverages'.

```
Here are my relations:

Customer has_many orders
Order has_many products through order_details
Product has_many Orders through order_details
Product belongs to Category
```

I tried this but it doesn't give all customers. It gives only customers who order Beverages.

```
 Customer.includes(orders: {products: :category}).where(categories: { category_name: "Beverages"})
```

Note: I don't want to filter Customer records. I need to apply filter on products because loading all records are useless in this case.

Comment: I never tried a chain that long, but maybe: `Category.where(category_name: "Beverages").first.products.orders.customers`

Comment: @iGian This does not eager load the records. Also we need all customers not the customers who have category Beverages.

Comment: Yes, sorry I read in hurry, shame on me. I missed the nesting. I read carefully now and your code works perfectly fetching customers who ordered beverages. But it is not clear to me what you really want to achieve _"..it doesn't give all customers."_ You intend to get also other products of the same category beverage bought by each customer fetched?

Answer (score 1):

Active Record doesn't have an API to do this, unfortunately.

If you only need a few known categories, you can do it by adding a custom association:

```
class Customer ..
  has_many :beverage_orders, -> { includes(products: :categories).where(categories: { category_name: "Beverages" }) }, class_name: "Order"
```

(and then `Customer.includes(:beverage_orders)`)

If you need to support arbitrary categories, your options get even worse... if there are few enough customers, I'd consider just skipping the include and accepting the N+1 query.

Otherwise, the next least bad option I can suggest is to do the query yourself:

```
customers = Customer.all # or whatever
beverage_orders = Order.includes(products: :categories).
                        where(categories: { category_name: "Beverages" }).
                        where(customer_id: customers).
                        group_by(&:customer_id)

customers.each do |customer|
  puts "#{customer.name} ordered #{beverage_orders[customer.id].size} beverages"
  # i.e., use `beverage_orders[customer.id]` instead of `customer.orders`
end
```

Comment: Thanks - Custom Association option is Excellent . But I need to pass argument to make to most useful. I know we don't have such provision but looking for alternative.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to filter your records, why you are using left join?
Try

```
Customer.joins(:orders).where(order: { product_id: Category.find_by(name: 'Beverages').products.pluck(:id) })
```

UPDATE:
As `where` clause will filter the base record, so it should filter your `Customer` model you need to customize `joins` to select proper products instead of filtering customers.

```
category_id = Category.find_by(name: "Beverages").id
Customer.joins(orders).joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN products ON products.id = orders.product_id AND products.category_id = #{category_id}")
```

Comment: left_outer_joins just behaves as includes . I mean the both result sets are identical.  I know joins are for different purpose it acts like Inner Join.

Comment: Why do you not use inner join if you need to filter records?
`Customer.joind(:orders).where(order: { product_id: Category.find_by(name: 'Beverages').products.pluck(:id) })`

Comment: I need all customers but only preload the products that are under particular category. For instance, if I have two customers and one ordered beverages and other one ordered different product. Then I need both customers and products relate to first one. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: As I understood you need to have join of all products, but when the product is not according to filter it should be nil
In this case you need to customize your `join` request.